# Interpretation Of Poisson regression model output

Tags: python, regression, modeling, poisson

I have made a poisson regression model to count the number of claims made by a policy holder over his/her policy period. The predicted values are float-point values which cannot be interpreted as one cannot have a fractional number of claims. Given below is the comparison of Actual values against the predicted values. Is there any transformation that can be used on the predicted values to get a whole number, something similar to the conversion of probabilistic outputs in a logistic regression model.

```
[![Model Summary][1]][1]

[![Actual v/s Predicted values][1]][1]


model = smf.glm("Number_Of_Claims ~ Number_Of_Users+Number_Of_Vehicles+Total_Miles+Category_Adults+Category_Senior+Category_MedExp+Territory_1+Territory_2+Territory_3+Territory_4+Territory_5+PIP_Exposure+Liability_Exposure", groups=None, 
        data=train,
            offset = train.Exposure_Term,
            family=Poisson())

pred_count = count_fit.predict(test, offset = test.Exposure_Term)
```

Comment: can you post your data example and your code?

Comment: I have posted the code but the data cannot be posted. The model equation represents the different fields the data has

Comment: I would recommend that you post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve